# getting error in setting navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

```
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, 0)));
```

Logcat shows that the problem is with the last line i.e.

```
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, 0)));
```

Comment: Is this the real code? Because if yes, you didn't initialize `navMenuTitles`.

Comment: What exactly is the error?  Did you actually create an array `navMenuTitles`, or did you only declare it?  And if you did create it, did you set `navMenuTitles[0]` to anything?

Comment: ya the error was because i dint declared navMenuTitles